# How to differ between empty Platform.String and null Platform.String^

Tags: windows-runtime

We're verifying that method arguments aren't null upon function entry, but this doesn't work for `Platform::String` (or `Platform.String`, no difference between C# or C++), since they overload the semantics of an empty string with a null instance.

Consider this, where the exception will always be thrown:

```
auto emptyString = ref new Platform::String();

// Now, emptyString.IsEmpty() will be true

if (emptyString == nullptr)
{
    throw ref new Platform::InvalidArgumentException();
}
```

The variable has a non-null value, but the `==` comparison operator is overloaded so comparing it to `nullptr` returns true since the `String` instance is empty.

As far as I can see this makes it impossible for us to make proper null checks at function entry for `String`s. Is that really so?

Comment: Ugh.  Having a default constructor on an immutable type is not a great idea.  Platform::String was crippled on purpose, you're supposed to use std::wstring.  Also consider StringReference to avoid copying strings.

Comment: Legacy code (yes, despite it being WinRT), we don't control that type.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are no "null strings" in Windows Runtime.  "Null" and "empty" mean the same thing with respect to strings.

Despite the fact that `Platform::String` uses the `^` syntax and looks like a reference type, it's not:  it's a projection of a Windows Runtime fundamental type, [`HSTRING`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/br205775.aspx).  A "null" HSTRING is indistinguishable from an empty HSTRING.

Even if a `Platform::String^` appears to be "null" (e.g. in the debugger), it is safe to treat it as if it were an empty string.  You can use it for concatenation, call `s->Length()`, etc.

---

In C#, a `string` can be null (and you can thus test it for null), but you will never get a null `string` from a Windows Runtime call and you cannot pass a null string as an argument to a Windows Runtime function (doing so will yield an exception at the ABI boundary).

Comment: Ah! This is my missing piece: *...you cannot pass a null string as an argument to a Windows Runtime function* - means we don't need to check for nullptr, because it just cannot ever be that.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that you are right. Any string which is set to `nullptr` is treated as an empty string. And if you even pass `nullptr` to the function you will never get the `NullReferenceException`.

```
bool NullPtrTest(Platform::String^ value)
{
  return value == nullptr;
}

bool EmptyTest(Platform::String^ value)
{
  return value->IsEmpty();
}

bool ReferenceEqualsWithNullPtrTest(Platform::String^ value)
{
  return Platform::String::ReferenceEquals(nullptr, value);
}

bool EqualsWithValueTest(Platform::String^ value)
{
  return value->Equals("test");
}

//...

NullPtrTest(nullptr); // true
NullPtrTest(ref new Platform::String()); // true
NullPtrTest("test"); // false


EmptyTest(nullptr); // true - no exception
EmptyTest(ref new Platform::String()); // true
EmptyTest("test"); // false


ReferenceEqualsWithNullPtrTest(nullptr); // true
ReferenceEqualsWithNullPtrTest(ref new Platform::String()); // true
ReferenceEqualsWithNullPtrTest("test"); // false


EqualsWithValueTest(nullptr); // false - no exception
EqualsWithValueTest(ref new Platform::String()); // false
EqualsWithValueTest("test"); // true
```

So, I see no way to find out whether the string was ever `nullptr`.

Comment: See my comment to James' answer